# macbook 16 Pro remove notch without losing desktop space

Tags: macbook-pro

I have macbook 16 pro and it has this stupid useless notch on top. Is there any way to remove it *without losing space*. I tried few programs in apple store but al the do is reduce even more desktop space by making black and not visible the part in the paralel as the notch is.
Please help is possible.

Also I would like to know is there any normal reason why they put this on macbook. I see only downsides and it is iritating (not only for me but I meet other people too with same opinion). How is it possible that MAC did not do some testing to see does this bothers people or something before releasing it. Interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'remove' it because there's no display there. It's not decorative, it contains other things - camera etc.

You're not really losing space, you're gaining it. Without it your display would be smaller by the depth of the notch.

Sure, it doesn't get much love, even from Apple fans; but it's a notch or a smaller display, and they went with a notch. Same on recent iPhones.

Comment: Oh now I get it. So before it was black in parallel with notch. We are actually gaining space as you said. Damn I misjudge it totally. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Yeah, there used to be a screen bezel containing the camera etc, now they brought the screen right to the edge, but they haven't yet figured out a way to make the camera work *through* the display, so until they do, it has to be a notch to contain all those bits.